# AngularJS: Is this the right way to write a directive handling updates in the model/content?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg, directive

I have to create a html page with svg elements that will be loaded from a json file. The json file is loaded using $http and returns a promise.

In the html file I have the following markup:

```
<ext-svg content="svg"></ext-svg>
```

`svg` will first contain undefined and when the json is loaded a valid svg content.

My directive is defined as:

```
 angular.module('myApp.directives')
      .directive('extSvg', function () {
        "use strict";

        return {
          restrict: 'E',
          scope: {
            content: '='
          },
          link: function (scope, element) {
            scope.$watch('content', function (value) {
              if  (value) {
                element.replaceWith('<svg>' + scope.content + '</svg>');
              }
            });
          }
        };
      });
```

The page rendered contains e.g.:

```
<svg><circle cx="10" cy="10" r="10" fill="yellow" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"></circle></svg>
```

It worked, but is it the correct way to implement this?

Comment: I would think it is a bit dangerous to *replace* the element entirely. Angular binds stuff to the element (the scope and other possibly), and you could be pulling the carpet under its feet. Better set the inner HTML.

Comment: I think HTML inside SVG does not work. For that reason I had to replace the element. But you are right, that this approach has problems. The replacement only works once ;-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps a diferent aproach using the ngSanitize module and directly bind the values from your controller, that way you dont actualy need a directive just to use the ng-bind-html anywhere you need to insert the SVG and no need for replace elements [Look at this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B87ca/2/)

so in your HTML

```
<div ng-bind-html="svg"></div>
```

and in your controller

```
$scope.svg = $sce.trustAsHtml('<svg><circle r="50"/></svg>'); //$sce needs to be injected in your controller
```